# Load Runner- Network Virtualization: No NV Graph Visualization and incorrect location wise Response Time

Tags: performance-testing, virtualization, loadrunner, microfocus, poc

I am trying to do a PoC on Load Runner- Network Virtualization.
PFB Scenario Details:

1. Demo Site: **https://petstore.octoperf.com/actions/Catalog.action**
2. Machine: **Office Laptop**
3. #Locations: **4**
   ->Location Configurations:
   [image]
4. 1 User to each location (total=4 Users).
5. Duration: 10-15 minutes

**Expected Result:**

1. Transaction having higher response time of the Location- London and Paris as compared to that of Mumbai and Goa.
2. NV Graphs Visualization- Packet Loss, Average Throughput, Average Bandwidth Utilization, etc.

**But in actual, I am getting below observations from my test:**

1. **Empty Graphs:**[image]
2. **Inconsistent response time from different locations (NV Insights):** Ideally considering latency, the response time of London and Paris should have been more than 1.6 seconds for each transactions. Important Transactions' SS given->[image], [image]
3. **Average Response time for different regions:** [image]

**Questions:**

- **Why I am not able to see the NV Graphs?**
- **Why the latency is not getting added to the response time?**

**I have tried adding the outbound for NV port in Firewall but the results remain the same. Can someone please guide what I am missing or doing wrong?**

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your code, ideally one transaction? everything from one trans_start to trans_stop.

Comment: hi @kenneth, here it is:
lr_start_transaction("03_selectItem");

 web_add_auto_header("Accept-Language", 
  "en-US,en;q=0.9");

 web_url("Catalog.action_2", 
  "URL=https://petstore.octoperf.com/actions/Catalog.action?viewCategory=&categoryId=FISH", 
  "Resource=0", 
  "RecContentType=text/html", 
  "Referer=https://petstore.octoperf.com/actions/Catalog.action", 
  "Snapshot=t5.inf", 
  "Mode=HTML", 
  LAST);
  
 web_link("FI-SW-01", 
  "Text=FI-SW-01", 
  "Snapshot=t8.inf", 
  LAST);

lr_end_transaction("03_selectItem",LR_AUTO);

Comment: Hi @kenneth, did you get something to ponder?

Answer (score 0):

My machine had more than one NIC (Wi-Fi and Ethernet) and it was not selected. Once I selected (Wi-Fi), got the expected results.

**Resource Link:** https://admhelp.microfocus.com/nv/en/nv-perform/en/Latest/help/Content/NV4HP/Active_adapter.htm?Highlight=active%20adapter

**Reference from LoadRunner Community:** https://community.microfocus.com/adtd/loadrunner/f/sws-loadrunner_sf/522531/load-runner--network-virtualization-no-nv-graph-visualization-and-incorrect-location-wise-response-time/1928166